# F# | Почему компилятор выдаёт ошибку FS0001?

Tags: компилятор, f#

У меня есть простенький код, в котором создаётся публичный класс. В нём один статический мембер (метод). Я его вызываю, пишет ошибку [FS0001](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/fs0001). Помогите, я понимаю, что означает код ошибки, но не понимаю, почему компилятор шизанулся.
Код:

```
open System

type calculator public () =
    static member add (x: int) (y: int) =
        printf "%d + %d = %d" x y (x + y)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    calculator.add(1, 2)
    0
```

Ошибка:

```
  Program.fs(12, 20): [FS0001] В данном выражении требовалось наличие типа
    "int"    
, но получен тип
    "'a * 'b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При объявлении функции вы объявили параметры по отдельности - `(x: int) (y: int)`, - но при вызове функции вы передаёте их почему-то в виде пары - `(1, 2)`.

Как параметры объявлены, так их нужно и передавать:

```
calculator.add 1 2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Просто я пришел с си-подобных языках))